# Alarm sent when DynamoDB WCU or RCU units are greater than X for Y amount of time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

Provisioned RCU and WCU are extremely expensive in DynamoDB and I spike them without autoscaling when I need to load test the applications. In the past, people have provisioned the tables and forgot to lower the capacity units and this resulted in an expensive monthly bill.

Is there a CloudWatch alarm or something similar that can send an alarm if DynamoDB's CU are set to X for a Y period of time? Or is there a better way to do this?

It would be nice if aws had a way to temporarily spike CU to a certain level and then automatically drop them back down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Create and publish a custom cloudwatch metric based on](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)

   [ProvisionedWriteCapacityUnits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/metrics-dimensions.html)
2. [Create an SNS topic to send the alert too](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SetupSNS.html)
3. [Create the cloud watch alert based on 1. to send to 2.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/creating-alarms.html) 
   Something like if ProvisionedWriteCapacityUnits is over X for too long trip the alert.